# if $b|a$ and $a<0,\,b>0$ then $b\geq a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hi fellas I have so far this: $$ a=bq \qquad \text{for some }q\leq -1$$
$$\exists k\leq -2:\, q=k+1$$
$$a=b(k+1)=bk+b/geq 0$$
$$ a\geq -b$$
But that's not the final result. :(

Comment: What is the equivalent of fellas in english ?

Comment: $a<0<b$ and done.

Comment: If $a=bq$, then $b|a$.I don't think you typed what you wanted to type.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $a\mid b$ is irrelevant, since
$$b>0>a$$
In other words, a negative number is always lesser than a positive number.

Comment: Yes I know, but I have to use divisibility.

Comment: @Erick If that's true, I don't think the problem is very instructive.

Comment: I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, $b|a$ iff $b|-a$ so there exists an integer $q \geq 1$ such that $-a=bq$ and also there exists another integer $k$ such that $q=k-1$ now since $-a>0$ it follows that:
$$0<-a=bq=b(k-1)=bk-b$$
So:
$$0<-a+b$$
$$a<b$$
I also think this problem isn't instructive at all.